# Camera and the eye (filtering information)

Tags: neuroscience, brain, vision

How does a camera recreate a very similar perceptual stimulus (through the photo) for us to see compared to the person directly viewing the object of interest with their eye?

My questions stems from what I've already learned about the visual system:

1) The retina receives information from the external world, but not 100% of the photons (the form of this information).

2) This information is then passed to the superior colliculus where further filtering, and changes to this information occurs.

3) It is next passed to the thalamus and then relays it to the occiptal lobe which interprets this information (another filtering process) causing us to perceive the external world in a particular way.

Is it that the camera captures the light information on the film that would otherwise have made contact with our retina? And then upon seeing the photo, that same information (or similar since the camera would not exactly capture it, but enough for us to notice that we are seeing what we expected to see) finally makes contact with the retina and then the process occurs as described in the points above?

If so, how does the camera do this!? Because I thought the camera would also be selective in which light it uses to recreate these images. And I'm incredibly doubtful that a camera simulates the filtering processes of the human brain. Moreover, it doesn't make sense that we would perceive the expected image in the photo if it was already based on the filtered information.

I am very curious and very confused. :)

-N

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you are asking how a camera works, not about biology.

Comment: I disagree. This question came from a friend who disagreed with the above explanation that the light information that encounters the retina is no longer the same once it reaches our visual cortex. He couldn't believe that our vision of the external world is not a true representation (whatever that is!).

So he then argued my original question in this post. If it isn't a true representation of the external world, how is it that a photo is able to provide a stimulus for almost the same visual response of an object of interest.